# Python imshow scale for normal distribution 2D numpy array data

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, imshow

I want to scale showed data from a numpy array with a normal distribution.
[Tutorial here](https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html#examining-a-specific-data-range) suggest use of clim, but in the example limits are hardcoded to `clim=(0.0, 0.7)`. Getting those values from previous histogram in tutorial:

[image: Histogram data example]

So, I need a pretty way to get **clim** values (without hardcoding), maybe using standard deviation (1 sigma, 2 sigma, 3 sigma) to get **principal** values:

[image: Normal distribution]

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the normal distribution, you can use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to fit a Gaussian function to the histogram.  Following the steps to read in the image and get the histogram, here's how you can fit the histogram:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Read image
img=mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')

# Get histogram
hist,bins,_ = plt.hist(img.ravel(), bins=256, range=(0.0, 1.0), fc='k', ec='k')

# Get centers of histogram bins
bin_centers = np.mean([bins[:-1],bins[1:]], axis=0)

# Define the Gaussian function
def gaussian(x, mu, sigma, amp):
    return amp*np.exp( -(x - mu)**2 / (2.*sigma**2))

# Curve fit
p_opt,_ = curve_fit(gaussian, bin_centers, hist)

# Get the fit parameters
mu, sigma, amp = p_opt
```

You can view the fit:

```
fit = gaussian(bin_centers, mu, sigma, amp)
plt.plot(bin_centers, hist)
plt.plot(bin_centers, fit)
```

[image]

Then you can use the fit parameters for `clim`.  First, here's the original image:

```
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

Here's limiting the pixel colors to be within 3-sigma:

```
plt.imshow(img, clim=(mu-3*sigma, mu+3*sigma))
```

[image]